# How to skew a color scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2, viridis

I am mapping annual precipitation in the USA, but the high values (blue) are so extreme that the rest of the map is not very informative.

I'm currently using `scale_fill_viridis_c(direction = -1, na.value = NA)` to generate the fill scale for the map. How can I "skew" the color scale to make this map more informative? In other words, how can the blue colors of the scale cover more values, leaving more color range for the rest of the range?

[image: USA precipitation]

Comment: Possible duplicate or at least useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76271146/restrict-viridis-colour-scale-to-between-two-values

Comment: `aes(fill = pmin(rain_variable, THRESHOLD_OF_PRETTY_HIGH_RAIN))` or `aes(fill = scales::pseudo_log_scale(rain_variable, sigma = FIDDLE_WITH_THIS))` or other functions to constrain / scale down very large values.

Comment: Or use e.g. a log transform.